# How to check if date between two date in php and sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I sent parameter date to check if that date between two date from database.
example date string parameter that i sent to API is "09/01/2020" which format is mm/dd/YYYY

this format also same for date string in database table column.

Now in database, I put date_start as "08/21/2020" and date_end as "09/05/2020"

My code is :

```
$date = $data["date"];
```

to get date string parameter that I sent to API.

Example table name is promo,
my code is :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM promo WHERE STR_TO_DATE('" . $date . "', '%M%M/%d%d/%Y%Y%Y%Y') 
between date_start and date_end";
```

But I did not get it.
How to correct that to get it?

Edited my latest code is like this but still did not get it:

```
$date = $data["date"];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $date);
$date = $date->format('m/d/Y');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM promo WHERE $date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(date_start, '%m/%d/%Y') AND
            STR_TO_DATE(date_end, '%m/%d/%Y')";
```

Comment: What is the datatype of the columns?

Comment: @Jens, datatype of the colums is string

Comment: Do not store dates as string. Store it as date

Comment: can i use corvert string to date?

Comment: Maybe like this `$sql = "SELECT * FROM promo WHERE STR_TO_DATE(?, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(date_start, '%m/%d/%Y') AND
            STR_TO_DATE(date_end, '%m/%d/%Y')";` using placeholder and prepared statement and pass the `$date`.

Comment: @Navid, did not work too if i use only $date = $data["date"]; which is string and replace ? with $date

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> Now in database, I put date_start as "08/21/2020" and date_end as "09/05/2020"

This is not best practice, and you should *always* store your dates as a proper date or datetime type in MySQL.  Had you done this, you would only need a range comparison in your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM promo
WHERE ? BETWEEN date_start and date_end;
```

If you *must* stick with your current design, then you would actually have to use `STR_TO_DATE` on the start and end dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM promo
WHERE ? BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(date_start, '%m/%d/%Y') AND
                STR_TO_DATE(date_end, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

To the `?` placeholder above, you should bind either a valid PHP date, or a valid MySQL date literal string.  But again, I strongly recommend fixing the design problem.

Comment: %m/%d/%Y or %m%m/%d%d/%Y%Y%Y%Y ?

Comment: The former.  `%m`, for example, represents the 2 digit month, it doesn't need to be repeated as you are doing.

Comment: do you mean like this : $date = $data["date"];
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '" . $date . "');
    $date = $date->format('m/d/Y');
    $sql = "SELECT *
FROM promo
WHERE '" . $date . "' BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(date_start, '%m/%d/%Y') AND
                STR_TO_DATE(date_end, '%m/%d/%Y')";

Comment: Maybe, but you should [use a prepared statement in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) rather than concatenating together your query string.